# How to loop through only the non-empty cell in a column in an excel sheet via VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

According to [this website](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=138243).

I think this should work:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In xxxSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
    'Do sth.
Next
```

which does not work. Is there something missing?

Comment: does not work how? does it give an error, or does it execute, but not skip the empty cells?

Comment: The code does not carry on after the xxxSheet is opened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be working solution:

```
For Each cell In xxxSheet.Range("B:B")
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        'do sth
    End If
Next
```

Also, if you want to loop until last filled cell, you could use following:

```
xxxSheet.Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
```

instead of

```
xxxSheet.Range("B:B")
```

Comment: Thanks. I was worrying that the IsEmpty Variant would take too long.

Comment: Maybe a safer way to use `If Trim(cell) <> "" Then`

Comment: You are right. To be precise: `If Trim(cell.Value) <> "" Then`.

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn What do you mean exacty by "filled cell"? Does it include those cell which has formula but is "empty" in terms of value?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Thanks for answering. Are the codes for rows and columns the same? (If not, would you mind if you post both?)

Comment: The above code is for finding row number of last filled cell in second column. Similairly, for finding column of last (rightmost) filled cell in certain row (let's say first row), one could use the following: `Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. Generally, it's little bit too broad for posting explanation in comment. You might want to take a look at articles about `xlUp`, `xlDown`, `xlToLeft`, `xlToRight`.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work, because you do not have formulas on column `B`. Put some formulas and some constants and try this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell      As Range
    Dim myRange     As Range

    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
    For Each myCell In myRange
        Debug.Print myCell.Address
    Next

    Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    For Each myCell In myRange
        Debug.Print myCell.Address
    Next

End Sub
```

The first loop would print the addresses of the formula cells, the second the addresses of the constants.
This is the ozgrid explanation about `SpecialCells`:

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/special-cells.htm

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)` is returning only cells with formulas that make numbers (ie. `=1+2`).

To keep things efficient, you only need to check up to the last filled row

```
For Each cell In xxxSheet.Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        'Do sth.
    End If
Next
```

If you really want you can use `SpecialCells()` to have a range containing no blanks to loop through. If you only have formulas or only constants, you could use `SpecialCells(xlFormulas)` or `SpecialCells(xlConstants)` respectively, but for a more general use case you will have to do do a combination of the two.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim searchRange As Range

' SpecialCells errors when there aren't cells instead of giving a useful value
On Error Resume Next 
Set searchRange = xxxSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
Set searchRange = xxxSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
Set searchRange = Union(xxxSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlConstants), _
    xxxSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlFormulas))
On Error GoTo 0

If searchRange Is Not Nothing Then ' Only continue if no blanks
    For Each cell In searchRange
        'Do sth.
    Next
End If
```